# Using Wireshark to inspect avro data over http

Tags: wireshark, avro

I would like to use wireshark to inspect avro data being sent over http. Is it possible to write a plugin for wireshark to convert avro's binary file format back to a human readable json object for inspection? If so is there an example of how I would accomplish this task?

Comment: any changes in last 3 years? perhaps you found answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible to get write a plugin to dissect avro data. Take a look at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ which contains a great deal of useful information. Chapter 9 in particular is concerned with protocol dissection.